# Printout all linear regression summary

Tags: apache-spark

I am using `println(s"Weights: ${lirModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${lirModel.intercept}")` to print out linear regression summary. This is not convenient because I want to print out everything all at once, like what we have in R `summary(lm1)`. Is there a way to do that in Spark?